# Core Plot - Zoom inicial para o gráfico de barras

Tags: ios, objective-c, barplot

Como faço para definir o zoom inicial baseado no valor máximo do eixo X e do eixo Y?

Exemplo:

Gráfico 1:

Valores Máximos:
X = 100;
Y = 110;

Gráfico 2:

Valores Máximos:
X = 180;
Y = 230;

Eu preciso que o zoom inicial mostre os dois gráficos igualmente. Pois se eu definir um zoom padrão, em um gráfico eu mostro por completo, mas em outro vai cortar parte do gráfico.

Comment: Do you speak Portuguese? If not, head up to [so]. Se sim, por favor traduza sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

`plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation: CPTDecimalFromFloat(-(maxValueY * 0.25)) length: CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxValueAxisY)];`

`plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation: CPTDecimalFromFloat(-3.0f) length: CPTDecimalFromFloat(xRangeBasedCount)];`

Nessa implementação eu defini o valor máximo e minimo que quero apresentar dentro do plotspace. Fiz alguns cálculos elevando o máximo de abrangência do eixo Y em 25% do valor máximo de uma barra para abranger toda a extensão da barra. Para o cálculo do eixo X, eu calculei através da quantidade de barras para que mostre todas as barras.